# Does Parallel Python PP always get back jobs'results in the order we created them?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

We are launching processes using PP and need to aggregate the results of jobs in the order we sent them to the server. Is there a kind of pile to control the aggregation of the results?

```
import pp, numpy
def my_silly_function(a,b):
   return a**4+b**15

# call the server (with pile?)
ppservers = ()
job_server = pp.Server(ppservers=ppservers, secret="password")
# launch jobs and aggregate them into a list 
jobs1=numpy.array[job_server.submit(my_silly_function, args=(w,w+40)) for w in xrange(1000)]
```

--> we hope that results will be returned in the same order we sent them (and thus don't need a lexsort to get them in the order we are asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  The order is maintained.  If you'd like to choose how to get your results back, with a blocking map, iterative map, or asynchronous (unordered) map, then you can use the fork of `pp` in `pathos`.  The `pathos.pp` fork also works with python 3.x.

```
>>> # instantiate and configure the worker pool
>>> from pathos.pp import ParallelPythonPool
>>> pool = ParallelPythonPool(nodes=4)
>>>
>>> # do a blocking map on the chosen function
>>> print pool.map(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
[1, 32, 729, 16384]
>>>
>>> # do a non-blocking map, then extract the results from the iterator
>>> results = pool.imap(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
>>> print "..."
>>> print list(results)
[1, 32, 729, 16384]
>>>
>>> # do an asynchronous map, then get the results
>>> results = pool.amap(pow, [1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8])
>>> while not results.ready():
>>>     time.sleep(5); print ".",
>>> print results.get()
[1, 729, 32, 16384]
```

get `pathos.pp` here: https://github.com/mmckerns